# Positioning/displaying JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing

I have Panel that contains JLayeredPane which contains two JPanels and each of them two JLabels.

```
Panel panel2 = new Panel();
JLayeredPane westP = new JLayeredPane();
westP.setLayout(null);
westP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));
westP.setBackground(Color.blue);

JPanel layerOne = new JPanel();
jl1 = new JLabel("player1: ");
layerOne.add(jl1);
layerOne.setBounds(5, 100, 50, 50);
jl1Add = new JLabel("");
layerOne.add(jl1Add);               
westP.add(layerOne,0, 0);
```

similar for another JPanel except

```
westP.add(LayerTwo,0,1);
```

and later:

```
panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel2.add(westP);
add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

later when I simply test it, I get lbl1, lbl1Add, lbl2 shown on GUI but not lbl2Add?

```
if (activeColour==RED)
{
   timesPlayedRed++;                  
   jl1Add.setText("");
   jl1Add.setText(String.valueOf((timesPlayedRed)));
   activeColour=YELLOW;
}
else
{
timesPlayedYellow++;
jl2Add.setText("");
jl2Add.setText(String.valueOf((timesPlayedYellow)));
activeColour=RED;
}
```

I am just trying out java and netbeans.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a working example. Modify the working example to meet your requirements.

Comment: @camickr made it work now. thanks a lot !